# Owl Carousel 2 not showing navigation dots

Tags: owl-carousel-2

I am trying out owl-carousel 2.3.4 (https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/) - all is fine except that the navigation dots are not showing. They aren't images so I don't know why it's not loading. I was wondering what I am doing wrong. I can see that it's working here (https://codepen.io/Ittisafur/pen/ggqzwY) but this uses owl-carousel version 1.3.3.

```
<style type="text/css">
.owl-carousel div.content
{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid red;
    min-height:150px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
}
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="owl-carousel">

  <div class="content">
      <p>Text 1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
      <p>Text 2</p>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
      <p>Text 3</p>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
      <p>Text 4</p>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
      <p>Text 5</p>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
      <p>Text 6</p>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
      <p>Text 7</p>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
      <p>Text 8</p>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
      <p>Text 9</p>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
      <p>Text 10</p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel(
    {
        center:false,
        items:5,
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
        dots: true,
        autoplay:true
    });  
});
</script>
```

Comment: Got this solved using slick.

Comment: create a JSFiddle so that we can view what's going on! And yes slick is always a better option, owl is just too confusing when you are dealing with dynamic options!

Answer (score 3):

Add the `owl-theme` class to your container:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the owl-theme class to your container:

```
       <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <div class="pr-2 pl-2 item">  </div>
            <div class="pr-2 pl-2 item">  </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: How is this answer is different from other answers?

Comment: I wanted to vote for the response of morten.c / mr501, but I did not allow it, so I left an equal response so that the community knows that this is solved.